# Intercept and Piggyback UIPageViewController's animation

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I'm looking for a way to animate some stuff while the panning animation is happening in a UIPageViewController.

Specifically the behavior I'm looking for is scale the alpha on a view as a user is scrolling(fade in and out with the page position).
If the user lets go before the page turn completes, the alpha will return to it's original point, animated along with the snap back. If the user completes a page turn, the alpha will go to it's furthest value.

So far, the only places I can find to check page turning is right before the turn at willTransitionToViewControllers: and after at didFinishAnimating:, neither of which is sufficient for the task.

thanks

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this with a page view controller. For this, and other reasons, I've found using a collection view with a screen sized cell and paging enabled gives me  the same look as a page view controller (with the scroll animation), but more control (since you have access to the scroll view delegate methods).

Comment: Tried this, works pretty well.